# Unusual Excel Sheet - Completely Blank, All Disabled

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

Anybody has an idea what is this strange worksheet in Excel? It contains one graph, but nothing else and almost all the controls in the ribbon are disabled. Please note this is not just blanked sheet with no borders/gray fill, there simply is no concept of cells here whatsoever.

If I wanted to do something like this, how would I achieve this?

[image: Strange Excel sheet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That type of sheet comes right-clicking a worksheet tab, then Insert, Chart, OK. Note that in VBA this is part of the `Sheets` collection but not part of the  `Worksheets` collection.

```
'this prints the Chart sheet's name along with all the worksheets' names
for i = 1 to Sheets.Count
    debug.print Sheets(i).Name
next i

'this only prints the worksheets' names and skips over the Chart sheet
for i = 1 to Worksheets.Count
    debug.print Worksheets(i).Name
next i
```